# Script to change settings in a program (filemaker pro 11)

Tags: filemaker

Looking for some help here. I do a bit of IT support for an organisation of about 200 people. Most of them use a database program called Filemaker Pro 11. Each user should have their own username that is set under the 'edit' menu -> 'preferences'. The edit menu is on the tool bar at the top of the screen, along with file, view, window etc. like as in MS Word for example.

Each user currently has a default username but the organisation wants everyone changed to a unique username. This means me visiting every machine and manually changing it. I was wondering if it would be possible to write a script to prompt users to make this change the next time they open the system? I'm not new to programming but I've never made a script like this before so wouldn't know where to start. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to script that change.

The user name you are referring to is the system (Windows or Mac) user name, and not the FileMaker user account. The default for the system user name is whatever they are logged in to their computer as. So, you could give people unique user names at the system level.

The option that is not default allows the user to change their system name. You can create a script that will open preferences for them, but there is no way to actually change it via a FileMaker script.

What you can do: Use the FileMaker account name instead of system name. The account name is much more reliable, follows the user across computers, is more secure, and *best of all* is (almost) totally scriptable.

I hope this helps. Sorry that what you want isn't possible inside of FileMaker.

Comment: Thanks very much for that. I can't understand why some people's usernames are set by default and some aren't. It's very annoying. I don't think I can use the filemaker account name because of the way that it's set up in this organisation. I think it's going to be a long week for me! Thanks for the feedback